# How to do if else condition on Pyspark columns with regex?

Tags: dataframe, if-statement, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe

|  | event_name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a-markets-l1 |
| 1 | a-markets-watch |
| 2 | a-markets-buy |
| 3 | a-markets-z2 |
| 4 | scroll_down |

This dataframe has event_name column

```
EXCLUDE_list = ["a-markets-buy", "a-markets-watch"]
expr = "a-markets"

new_df = df.withColumn("event_name",
                           when(
                               (col('event_name').rlike(expr)
                                & ~(col('event_name').isin(EXCLUDE_list)),'a-markets'))
```

I am trying to only filter out and replace those values which has "a-markets" and not in the EXCLUDE_list list  by "a-markets"

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = df.withColumn("event_name",
                           when(
                               (col('event_name').rlike(expr)
                                & ~(col('event_name').isin(EXCLUDE_list)),'a-markets').otherwise(col("event_name"))
```

Putting a otherwise did the trick